# Dissecting an ERB to HAML conversion example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Directly rom the HAML tutorial:

```
<div class='item' id='item<%= item.id %>'>
  <%= item.body %>
</div>
```

and the answer is

```
.item{:id => "item#{item.id}"}= item.body
```

I understood the reason for first `.item`, Ok it is a class so we declare it that way.
I also understood the hash, Ok when we have attributes we create a hash for it.
The part I couldn't understand how it is converted is  `"item#{item.id}"`
Shouldn't be some sort of `"="` sign somewhere? because it was saying when we want to calculate Ruby code use that `"="` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{:id => "item#{item.id}"}` is evaluated as hash in ruby code by Haml, so you don't need `=`

Comment: what is the "#" for? Is it Ruby's string interpolation?

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark Specifically, hash-brackets `#{}` is string interpolation, and it only works from within double-quotes (`""`). Single-quotes (`''`) will print the literal string without interpolation.